# Convert Equation to Matrix Form

Tags: linear-algebra

I have the following equation which I cannot seem to figure out how to convert to matrix form (such that I can compute it efficiently in code).

$\Sigma_m = \sum_i r_{im}(x_i - \mu_m)(x_i-\mu_m)^T$

Where $x_i$ and $\mu_m$ are vectors.

I am pretty sure that $\sum_i(x_i - \mu_m)(x_i-\mu_m)^T = ZZ^T$ where $Z$ is the matrix whose $i^{th}$ row is $x_i - \mu_m$.  But I'm not sure how to incorporate the $r_{im}$ term

Comment: Is $x_i$ a row or column vector?

Comment: its a column vector.  so the result should be a matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting $d_{i,m} = x_i - \mu_m$ for the $N$ difference vectors then 
$$
\Sigma_m = \sum_{i=1}^N r_{im} d_{i,m} \, d_{i,m}^T
$$
If $x_i$ is a row vector, then this is a weighted sum of the $N$ scalar products $d_{i,m}\, d_{i,m}^T = \lVert d_{i,m} \rVert^2$, with weights $r_{im}$. Thus a number.

If $x_i$ is a column vector, then $d_{i,m} \, d_{i,m}^T$ is the matrix $Z_{i,m} = (z_{jk})$ with 
$$
z_{jk} = (d_{i,m})_j \, (d_{i,m})_k
$$
and $\Sigma_\mu$ is the weighted sum of those $N$ matrices $Z_{i,m}$, with weights $r_{im}$. This is a matrix.

Comment: Right.  This is what I thought initially, but I had hoped there was a way to express the weighted sum of the $N$ matrices as some kind of concise matrix/vector product or something.  I suppose this is not possible.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Hm. Let me think.

Comment: It is not your suggested matrix. That one would contain vectors $d_{i,m}$ for different $i$. While the ones showing up, in the matrices which I named $Z_{i,m}$ use only the $d_{i,m}$ for one particular index $i$.

Comment: Out of the box, for optimization I see no more than symmetry $z_{jk} = z_{kj}$.

Answer (score 0):

As far as, I can see, your term $r_{im}$ will be multiplied with each entry of the $i^{th}$ row for a particular value of {m}. You can also say that it is embedded with each of the term.